# How can i create a richtextBox with single line?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I want to create custom editor from richtextBox which have intelligence and syntax highlighting feature.But i want the control to be single line and if the content is long to fit the Actual width , the left part of the content will be hidden as normal text box works. My Question is how i can create a richtextBox with single line? 
I can not use text box because it does not support text highlighting and it is relatively easy to do that using richtextBox .

Answer (score 0):

Try using AcceptReturn="False".

```html
<RichTextBox Height="129" Name="richTextBox1" Width="262" AcceptsReturn="False" />
```

Comment: This will simply refuse to accept Return to write line endings for multiple lines, it has nothing to do with "the left part of the content will be hidden as normal text box works", see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Try to first add a single line TextBox control, and set its size; then change its class to RichTextBox ( see [Replacing a WinForms TextBox with a RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330286/replacing-a-winforms-textbox-with-a-richtextbox) ); then finally set the ScrollBars property to `None` - this should give an appearance and behavior almost like a single-line TextBox.